# Can a Battle Oracle take the Marshall dedication?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, oracle

When an Oracle chooses the Battle mystery, they become trained in all martial weapons belonging to a chosen weapon group (e.g. Sword, Axe).

A requirement of the Marshall dedication is that the character is 'trained in martial weapons'.

Is the Oracle therefore eligible to take the dedication, or would they first need to take the Weapon Proficiency general feat?

Comment: While it's outside the scope of the answer, those looking to get the Marshal archetype for their oracle at level 2 could grab the Weapon Proficiency general feat at level 1 as a human or half-human using the Versatile Heritage or General Training Ancestry Feat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### No

The Battle Oracle gains

> Choose one weapon group that embodies your mystery. You are trained in all martial weapons of that group.

On your character sheet this looks like "Trained in martial *swords*" or (more correctly but less realistically) "Trained in shortsword, rapier, longsword, greatsword, [...]".

Trained in martial weapons is a specific benefit that encompasses *all* martial weapons, not just some. If you look at [classes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=7) that provide proficiency with all martial weapons, they similarly exclude the implied word. [Rogues](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=10), by contrast, begin Trained in rapier, sap, shortbow, and shortsword but similarly would not qualify.

The Weapon Proficiency Feat would provide Trained to all martial weapons (because the Oracle already has all simple) and qualify you for the Marshal Archetype (assuming you have Diplomacy or Intimidation).